# Visual studio test explorer doesn't show Author

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am using visual studio 2022 with NUnit VS template.
I have NUnit3 Test Adapter version 4.2.1 & NUnit version 3.13.3
I have added Author attribute to my test, but it doesn't appear in test explorer.
How will I get the Author in place of no traits.

[image: Code]

Comment: Try saving all and reloading visual studio.

Comment: You might need to group your tests by "Trait".

Comment: Did you build the solution? Try cleaning and rebuilding. Failing that, try closing all Visual Studio windows, and deleting the `.vs` folder at the root of the solution.